# Checklist filter SXA not filtering itself

Tags: sxa, content-search, search-facet

I'm using two checklist filters with two different facets for each one that are using a computed index field to populate their data.
Each one is filtering the search results and the other filter data correctly, but not filtering its data.
As shown in the image below for FILTER BY INFORMATION filter.

Before Filtering :
[image]

After filtering :[image]

Still other choices are there although the search results aren't containing all these data.
It was working well when the facet was using ordinary field not a computed one.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option to do that. Checklist Filter has "Collapse on selection" checkbox in renderings parameters dialogue which when selected will make a filter to collapse when the value is selected.

Take a look here:

[image]